# Difference between :checked and :selected when working with option elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Both `:checked` and `:selected` seem to provide equal results when working with `<option>` elements. Is there any advantage to using one over the other? If `:selected` does the same thing as `:checked`, what is the reason for it to be included in jQuery at all?

Example:

```
<p class="p1">Select a value</p>
<p class="p2">Select a value</p>

<select>
    <option value="a">Option one</option>
    <option value="b">Option two</option>
</select>


$('select').on('change', function(){

    $('.p1').text(function() { 
        return $('option:selected').text();
    });

    $('.p2').text(function() { 
        return $('option:checked').text();
    });
});
```

[JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/tovubicoda/3/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector), it seems that `:selected` is identical to `:checked` with the exception that it only matches `option` elements. This is corroborated by HTMLOptionElement being the only element type in the DOM to have a `selected` property (which is what `:selected` uses to test the selectedness of an element). In other words, when you're only interested in `option` elements, both selectors are identical — except `:selected` is non-standard.

Since the documentation itself recommends using standard selectors to maximize performance (and because why would you *not* use a standard selector over a non-standard one if given the choice?), I don't think there is any reason to use `:selected` in any situation ever. I can't think of any situation in which `*:selected` would be preferable to `option:checked` (seriously, when was the last time you used a pseudo-class of this kind without a type selector?).

Perhaps the reason it was included in jQuery was because Selectors 3 (in which `:checked` appears) wasn't yet standardized at the time jQuery was born, but `:checked` has been in the spec [since 2000](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-selectors-20000410), so I'm not entirely convinced that's really the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, :selected is for SELECT OPTIONS elements.  :checked is for CHECKBOX elements.

```
<p class="p1">Select a value</p>
<p class="p2">Select a value</p>
  <p class="p3">Select a value</p>
  <p class="p4">Select a value</p>

<select>
<option value="a">Option one</option>
<option value="b">Option two</option>
</select>

  <input type="checkbox" value="C" />


$('input').on('change', function(){

  $('.p1').text(function() { 
    return $('option:selected').text();
  });

  $('.p2').text(function() { 
    return $('option:checked').text();
  });

  $('.p3').text(function() { 
    return $('input[type="checkbox"]:selected').val();
  });

   $('.p4').text(function() { 
    return $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val();
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/zadocokule/edit?html,js,output