# What is difference between these two jQuery selectors: 'select option:selected' and 'select :selected'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose we have a code:

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4" selected>Fourth</option>
  <option value="5">Fifth</option>
</select>
```

What is difference between these two jQuery selectors:

1. `$('select option:selected')`
2. `$('select :selected')`

Using them I can get selected options of the `<select>` tag. Does these selectors are the same?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. `:selected` is jQuery's non-standard equivalent of the standard `option:checked`, which means `option:selected` and `:selected` are equivalent. See [Difference between :checked and :selected when working with option elements in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088774/difference-between-checked-and-selected-when-working-with-option-elements-in-j/44088820#44088820)

Using `:selected` is pointless anyway. Just use `option:checked` and get the performance benefits of native selector evaluation for free. [Even jQuery's documentation itself recommends this.](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector) I'm not sure why `:selected` hasn't been deprecated at this stage.