# Why is the selected <option> css-queried with :checked, but the HTML and Javascript is using selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

You can grab the selected option from `<select>` but if you have `<select multiple>` and you need to do something dynamically with the selected options.

You could querySelect the :checked or you could select all the options and filter the .selected

Can someone explain this inconsistency?

```js
function run() {
  let optionChecked;
  let optionSelected;
  try {
    optionChecked = document.querySelector("option:checked");
  } catch (e) {}

  try {
    optionSelected = document.querySelector("option:selected");
  } catch (e) {}

  console.log('selector: option:checked: ', optionChecked) // chosen option
  console.log('selector: option:selected: ', optionSelected) // undefined

  console.log('js-property: option.checked: ', optionChecked.checked) // undefined
  console.log('js-property: option.selected: ', optionChecked.selected) // true

}
```

```css
/*
* never used.
*/

option:selected {
  color: brown;
}


/*
* Even tho not supported - when inspecting the element, we see the css-selector match
*/

option:checked {
  color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<h2>Example</h2>
<select name="" id="select1">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <!-- Invalid -->
  <option value="b" checked>b</option>
   <!-- Valid -->
  <option value="c" selected>c</option>
  <option value="d">d</option>
</select>

<button onclick="run()">run</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [early drafts of Selectors 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-selectors-20000410), `:checked` was first proposed as `:selected` circa 2000. However, no revision of the draft actually contains a definition for `:selected`, so I can only guess it was proposed `:selected` before entering the drafts as `:checked`.

Since it was specified to apply to both the `checked` and `selected` attributes in HTML (presumably because they both serve the same purpose in a form), there was no need to have two pseudo-classes meaning the same thing. Plus, the goal was to decouple Selectors from HTML, so having one unique name for this pseudo-class was ideal. For whatever reason, when deciding what to name this pseudo-class, the authors of the spec went with `:checked`. I looked through the www-style mailing list archives from 1999–2000 and unfortunately couldn't find anything publicly discussing this decision.

The `.checked` and `.selected` DOM properties simply mirror their HTML attribute namesakes, and are unrelated to anything in Selectors. This is why you'll find that the `.checked` property only appears in [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement); and `.selected`, only in [HTMLOptionElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).

jQuery contains a `:selected` pseudo-class that's basically a JavaScript reimplementation of `:checked` that only applies to `option` elements. [Make of that what you will](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088774/difference-between-checked-and-selected-when-working-with-option-elements-in-j/44088820#44088820), but I recommend just ignoring it. I'm only mentioning it as trivia.